# Selecting random rows

Tags: postgresql

Hi all,
      My requirement is simple.I want to select random rows from a table.

For example my table having 10 rows I want to select any three rows randomly.Is there any way in psql.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `random` function.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY random() LIMIT 3;
```

Answer (score 4):

Please be aware that once your table grows the "order by random/limit" approach will be slow, since it requires a whole table scan.

See http://blog.rhodiumtoad.org.uk/2009/03/08/selecting-random-rows-from-a-table/ for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this !

```
$ select * from table_name order by random() limit 3 ;
```