# How to retrieve randomized data rows from a postgreSQL table?

Tags: c#, postgresql, random

I have a table on a PostgreSQL server database with almost **3 million** rows and I need to save all rows to a CSV file. The problem here is that the rows must be saved in a different **random** order each time I run the process.

Worth noting that it's a C# WinForms app.

I tried loading the data into a List<> and using a shuffling algorithm but it took forever to finish, and I realy need it to be fast. I think doing it directly in the query will be much faster but I don't have a clue on how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, you can just `ORDER BY` a random function of your database flavor, like

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM()
```

This might be as slow as shuffling the list, depending on the database server or product.

Comment: It took 16 seconds to return the query, fairly acceptable and way faster than the shuffling. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

See this question [Selecting random rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049324/selecting-random-rows)

See this wonderful link [Depesz MY THOUGHTS ON GETTING RANDOM ROW](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2007/09/16/my-thoughts-on-getting-random-row/)