# randomize drupal database query

Tags: sql, database, drupal

I'm executing a query which I want to randomize query results from a drupal database.

here's what I have done...

```
$res=db_query("SELECT DISTINCT nid FROM content_type_event ORDER BY RANDOM()");
```

but this query doesn't work. what's wrong with this query? please help me to solve this?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: it shows nothing, but when I remove ORDER BY RANDOM() from the query it works, is there any way I can randomize query results with db_query() function?

Comment: Why don't you randomize the rows on the PHP side after you have retrieved them?

Comment: currently I have used that way to do it, but I thought this approach will be quite good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not tell us which database engine you are using, but maybe `ORDER BY RAND()` would be better.

**Update**: okay, PostgreSQL uses `RANDOM()` and not `RAND()` so that's okay. I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472871/how-to-retrieve-randomized-data-rows-from-a-postgresql-table) which seems to suggest that `ORDER BY RANDOM()` should work and the error is likely to be elsewhere. Maybe it's `DISTINCT` that is screwing things up; try your query again without `DISTINCT`.

Comment: I use postgresql... I used ORDER BY RAND() too but no luck :(

Comment: you are a savior thanks a lot, indeed DISTINCT screwed it up earlier... :-)))

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to be using `ORDER BY RAND()` instead.

Also there is a bit you may want to know about `ORDER BY RAND()`'s performance if you are getting a considerable amount of results that will be randomized:

http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/

EDIT: Just saw your comment that you are using PostgreSQL, this looks like it could be helpful: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/466.cfm

Sorry I can't be a lot of much help, I don't use PostgreSQL myself

Comment: Links you shared, helped me a lot to get an idea of using different methods instead using random()... Thanks a lot...